# npm install successfully but node web.js erros w: "Error: Cannot find module"

Tags: macos, node.js, npm

I'm working to get node running on a new mac. I downloaded the installed at http://nodejs.org/

I then git cloned my node repo, ran npm install and npm update, and then node web.js which then errors with:

```
$ node web.js 

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/me/Sites/mysite-node/node_modules/pg/lib/native/../../build/default/binding'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/Sites/mysite-node/node_modules/pg/lib/native/index.js:12:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
```

I'm new to node, any ideas or suggestions on where to look? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the postgresql libraries on your machine.  For example under Fedora you'd:

```
yum install postgresql.x86_64
yum install postgresql-server.x86_64
```

If you already had pg install you'd need to rebuild it:

```
npm rebuild pg
```

Then to verify everything is working at the terminal type:

```
node
```

Then in the node REPL type:

```
var pg = require('pg').native
```

And you shouldn't get an error

Answer (score 0):

The Error shows that npm installation of the pg module has not built the native bindings properly. Modify your code as follows:

```
//var pg = require('pg').native;
var pg = require('pg');
```